# How do I set IE10 to allow a link to Windows Explorer to open?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Our intranet has a Document Management system whereby a user can search for a file and then click a link (file:///) to open the containing folder with Windows Explorer.

Since moving to IE10, we have noticed that it doesn't work on some machines. (User clicks the link, but nothing happens.) I have tracked it down to whether a user has allowed / denied Windows Explorer access with the following pop-up:

[image]

I am assuming the ones that don't work are failing because the user has clicked "Don't Allow" and checked the "Do not show me the warning" check box.

How can I change this setting in IE10 if the popup is not being shown?

Answer (score 3):

You have fallen victim to IE's vicious Protected Mode Elevation Policies

Open the registry editor and locate the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Low Rights\ElevationPolicy\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
```

This key controls the process integrity elevation policy for `explorer.exe` when launching from Protected Mode in IE

If the user pressed "Don't allow", you should be able to see a DWORD value named `Policy`, set to `0`. Set it to `3`, and explorer.exe will launch the `file:///` links silently without prompting in the future.

It's all carefully explained in [this developer guide at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462(v=vs.85).aspx#wpm_elebp)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1. Go to Tools → Internet Options → Security → Local Intranet → Sites → Advanced
2. Add the site that has open folder and files functionality.